# How to hide content on specific cells only, despite using dequeueReusableCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I would like to hide some elements in a custom cell when we overpass a specific number of row. I added more row than the ones visible, because I needed to scroll until the last row without the bouncing effect. But now I have more cells, and I don't need the cells after row > 13.

I tried to setNeedsDisplay the cell with a if else, but the dequeue... method has a bad effect on the cells, when I scroll up, back to the previous cells, they don't have the texts anymore, like the row > 13. Is there a way to use the dequeue method, and let the content for the rows < 13, and remove the content for the rows > 13 ?

Here is some code :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var identifier = ""

    if tableView == self.tableView{
        identifier = "MyCell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier) as MyCell
        if indexPath.row < 14 {
            cell.showContent = true
            cell.label.text = "test\(indexPath.row)"
        }
        else {
            cell.showContent = false
            cell.label.text = ""
            cell.addItem.text = ""
        }
        cell.setNeedsDisplay()
        return cell
    }


//MyCell
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
if !showContent {
    label.text = ""
    addItem.text = ""
}
else {
    let path = UIBezierPath()//custom separator that should not be drawn for row > 13
```

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just turn off the "Bounces" checkbox for the table view if you don't want bouncing?

Comment: You can also set it in code with `tableView.bounces = false`

Comment: @rdelmar the last cell has to go up to a point in the view. It should not stay at the bottom, so this makes the scroll possible and I stop the drag in scrollViewDidScroll if the current index of the cell is > 13. But I don't find a way to hide the content for the last cells only, because dequeue... changes all the cells then.

Comment: @RobNapier same message as above :)

Comment: Rob's answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't modify the text this way in `drawRect`. You already modified the labels in cellForRow. That's all you need.

That said, this isn't how I would do it. I'd probably create a different cell with its own identifier for empty cells. That way they can be really simple and you don't have to do things like `cell.setNeedsDisplay()` to get rid of the separator line. So in cellForRow, just return one kind of cell for data rows, and a different kind of cell for empty rows. There's no rule that says all the cells have to be the same class.